# uniform1i switches to wrong texture unit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, webgl

I'm trying to convert an old OpenGL screen saver to WebGL. It's supposed to render a Möbius strip with numbers from "00" to "23" written along it like the numbers on an analog clock's face. This is what the original looks like:

[image: Möbius Clock]

For reasons I don't fully remember now, the texture of the strip is divided into 4 separate files named `hours?.bmp`, where the `?` stands for `0`..`3`. Accordingly, I tried to load each file into a different texture unit as follows

```js
    for (const which of [gl.TEXTURE0, gl.TEXTURE1, gl.TEXTURE2, gl.TEXTURE3]) {
      const texture = loadTexture(gl, `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/texture/hours${which - gl.TEXTURE0}.bmp`);
      gl.activeTexture(which);
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    }
```

and render the whole ring as 4 triangle strips (each one spanning 180°), changing the sampler before rendering each piece:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    gl.uniform1i(uniforms.sampler, i);
    // Render the ith piece.
    // ...
}
```

For some reason, however, instead of using the four textures in the expected order (0, 1, 2, 3), the program uses `TEXTURE1`, `TEXTURE2`, `TEXTURE3` and then `TEXTURE3` again. Maybe it's just some silly coding error on my behalf but I've been staring at the code for two straight days now and couldn't figure it out.

The code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/roninbar/mobius/commits/stackoverflow) and you can see a live version on [GitHub Pages](https://roninbar.github.io/mobius/).

Comment: The active texture unit is a globale state. Does `loadTexture` use `gl.TEXTURE0` for all 4 textures? Or does it not even change the texture unit and use the randomly set texture unit? Is the last texture bound to texture unit 0 and 3 in the end? What happens if you use the texture units 1 to 4?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I followed the [WebGL tutorial on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Using_textures_in_WebGL). `loadTexture` doesn't call `gl.activeTexture`. It creates a new `WebGLTexture` and returns it to the main program, which then calls `gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE?)` and `gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture)`.

Comment: The 2nd line in `loadTexture` is `gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture)`. `gl.bindTexture` binds the texture to the active texture unit. The active texture unit is a global state and can be changed with `gl.activeTexture`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks! I added a call to `gl.activeTexture` in `loadTexture` and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gl.bindTexture` binds the texture to the active texture unit. The active texture unit is a global state and can be changed with `gl.activeTexture`. Every time `gl.activeTexture` is called, the active texture unit is changed. This affects all subsequent calls to `gl.bindTexture`.
The 2nd line in `loadTexture` is `gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture)` and binds the texture to the randomly set texture unit.
Use the texture unit 0 (`gl.TEXTURE0`) in `loadTexture` to load the texture. After loading the textures, bind them to specific texture units. Alternatively, you can pass a specific texture unit to `loadTexture` and use it when loading the texture.